# Why is this question closed as opinion based?

Tags: discussion

[Why doesn't the Mac OSX finder have a Cut option?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23678/why-doesnt-the-mac-osx-finder-have-a-cut-option)

This question is closed because it is supposedly opinion based. That doesn't seem to be true. There might actually be a reason why a cut menu item is not available in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

There *might* be a reason why it doesn't have a Cut option, but the only way anyone is going to know for sure is if;

a) The particular developer who consciously decided not to implement that feature wrote an article / was interviewed about it or anything like that that means there is a published, authoritative source on that online somewhere.

b) That particular developer is actually a member of UX.SE and decided to post his reasoning as an answer.

Now both of those options are highly unlikely. And it could be easily argued that if there *is* a published article about it then the question asker should've found it during their research before asking the question. Otherwise it's just a question stating *"go and do a Google search for me to find out if this developer ever answered this question"* and that's not really what Stack Exchange is about - we expect people to have done all the research before asking a question. We're not a personal Google search service; we're here to answer specific questions that have a useful answer.

Because it is so unlikely that there is any published article about this particular design decicion out there that means the only option open to people when answering is to speculate and give their own belief as to why that situation exists. Ergo - Primarily Opinion Based.

Now if the Apple dev happens to turn up, leave a comment on the post or flag it for mod attention stating that it was him / her that made the decision then we can reopen it and let them leave an answer. But leaving it open will attract more opinion-based answers (we've already had to delete several really bad 'answers' from that question).

Comment: I am pretty sure the implementation of or a lack of a feature in OSX is not decided by a single developer.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander: *Are* you sure though? That's one of the issues. Nobody can 100% guarantee they have the answer unless they were involved in it. Also, questions around why *didn't* somebody do something are going to be even harder than "why *was* this decision made" so that makes this Mac Cut option question even harder to answer. They answer may well just be "well we just forgot about it". It's hard to get a definitive answer to these, hence the closure.